# What is magical power in the potter universe and how are these powers compared?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort, albus-dumbledore, fantastic-beasts, gellert-grindelwald

In the most recent movie `Fantastic Beasts, Crimes of Grindelwald` the minister said to Dumbledore somthing like "Only you can take on Grindlewald, because he's so powerful". That made me somehow wonder. I know there are many types of magical abilities (Foreseeing, Beast transformations, Mind reading, ...) but what makes a wizard more powerful than others?
The most powerful wizards mentioned are: Dumbledore, Grindelwald and Voldemort (Maybe the fathers of Hogwarts). I don't recall hearing people discribe Harry as powerful.
What makes a wizard more powerful than others? And why can we say that Dumbledore and Grindlewald at their peak were the most powerful?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a duplicate. The question Jenayah cites is asking *how does a wizard get powerful* while this question is more about how you compare the different magical abilities.

Comment: @JohnRennie the comparison part is tackled (of sorts) in [What does it mean that a Wizard is more powerful than another?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186277/98028) which is closed as dupe of the above, hence the suggested dupe-target. I think if this is left open, that other one should be reopened as well. (it's only my opinion, though :) )

Comment: In this particular context, power is, by definition, the ability to defeat other wizards.