# Why didn't Arthur Weasley help Molly when she was dueling Bellatrix?

Tags: harry-potter, character-motivation

When Molly Weasley and Bellatrix are dueling during The Battle of Hogwarts, why didn't Arthur Weasley help?

Forgive me, as I don't know where he is during that duel in the books, I can only remember the film where they place him right behind her.

If he was in the vicinity and saw/heard, regardless of whether she could handle herself, surely his natural instinct is to join in and help defend her?

Comment: Maybe he was sick of her and secretly wanted Bellatrix to win.

Comment: "Right behind someone" is basically the worst possible position for aiding them in a duel, no matter what the weapons are.

Comment: @Bellatrix How would **you** know Arthur Weasley was sick of his wife? How would you know he wanted **you** to win? Did he tell you? ;-)

Answer (score 11):

Arthur was busy doing other things at the time.  Just before, he was seen in a different part of the battle:

> Arthur and Percy flooring Thicknesse

Also, the duel was pretty short, and Molly really did not need help:

> “OUT OF MY WAY!” shouted Mrs. Weasley to the three girls,
>   and with a swipe of her wand she began to duel. Harry watched with
>   terror and elation as Molly Weasley’s wand slashed and twirled, and
>   Bellatrix Lestrange’s smile faltered and became a snarl. Jets of light
>   flew from both wands, the floor around the witches’ feet became
>   hot and cracked; both women were fighting to kill.

If I were him, I would certainly not want to intrude on that, even if I wasn't busy flooring the Minister of Magic with my son.

Comment: How _did_ Molly kill Bellatrix? Clearly wouldn't have been the killing curse - Molly would never use that.  Must have been some other spell which isn't unforgivable.

Comment: @Tim Check out [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4387/51142) answer and its comments

Comment: @Tim Not very well, thank you! :P

Answer (score 1):

Mrs. Weasley specifically refused all help:

> "NO!" Mrs. Weasley cried as a few students ran forward, trying to come to her aid. "*Get back*! She is mine!"

This occurred pretty early on in her duel with Bellatrix, so Mr. Weasley would probably not have been able to help her prior to her exclamation even if he had wanted to (he himself was coming off a duel with Pius Thicknesse). Once she made this exclamation, Mr. Weasley might not have dared to get involved (especially considering that throughout the books Mrs. Weasley is portrayed as the dominant personality in the relationship).

Comment: Good find, but this only mentions *students* trying to help her, which doesn't answer why her husband didn't at least *try* to help.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Are you asking why he didn't at least try *before* the exclamation or *after* the exclamation? (Or both?)

Comment: Who wants Bellatrix dead anyway? :P She’s awesome! ;)

Comment: @Bellatrix Depends which Bellatrix we're referring to.

Comment: @Randal'Thor In any case, I edited to address both before and after.