# Do we know of any non "Avada Kedavra" killing spell?

Tags: harry-potter, avada-kedavra

Is there any spell other than *Avada Kedavra* that immediately kills?

(To be clear, not any spell that can wound and later kill, such as *diffindo* or *sectumsempra*.)

So does such a spell exist, and if so- What is it and why isn't it one of the unforgivable curses?

Comment: Avada Kedavra is the only spell that kills *as its only effect*.

As you've pointed out, there are umpteen ways to use the effect of a violent spell to kill someone (or cleverly killing someone with a non-violent spell), but they all do so by ***causing an effect other than the death of the person.*** 

Spells that are seen to be fatal (or described as *nearly* killing someone, or that cause an effect that could have been fatal if untreated) include Fiendfyre, Sectumsempra, Confringo, Diffindo and Stupefy.

Comment: @Valorum- OK. I was asking this question because someone told me that Molly didn't use Avada Kedavra to kill Bellatrix, so I was curious if someone knew anything about it.

Comment: see https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-was-this-character-killed-without-avada-kedavra

Comment: "Killing" is an outcome, not a function.  I mean, you could kill someone by levitating a piano above their head, and then not levitating it anymore.  So then that spell becomes a killing spell.  A lot of spells could be killing spells.  I suppose you can then ask whether there is a spell that does *exactly the same thing* as Avada Kedavra, but then it would just be Avada Kedavra.  Unless it also comes in purple or some such.

Answer (score 5):

Lack of evidence answers are somewhat disappointing, but anyway...

- There is no mention of such killing curses in the HP novels
- There is no mention of such killing curses in the HP movies
- There is no mention of such killing curses in the (first two) FB movies

Speculation: I hardly believe that, what with the inventiveness of human kind when it comes to killing other humans that magical peoples have only come up with one curse specifically designed to kill.

Comment: Answer to speculation: there are many spells that kill creatively from side effects, but the hardness of testing while inventing this one make this spell worse. Also there are no two different spells that do the same thing in general.

Comment: Of course! The OP, if I read correctly, is looking specifically for spells that, by design, are intended for the purpose of killing a person. Not so much spells that kill a person as a knock on effect.

Answer (score 3):

There are spells that could potentially kill immediately, such as Reducto, which would blow someone apart right then and there. There are likely more, but as Elemtilas noted, we really don't have a lot to go on.

Otherwise, the only other spells I can think of would fall into the category of causing harm that leads to death eventually.